# Spring-boot app using hibernate, SpringBoot, MySql and JSP

Tags: mysql, hibernate, maven, spring-boot, jsp

I am pretty new to java web frameworks and would like to build a SpringBoot app using those two and probably jsp(I could use jpa, but I am more familiar with jsp).

So my question is how do I implement it with JSP, Hiberante ?

I have already tried implementing SpringBoot and hibernate so I made `hibernate.cfg.xml` and `myClass.hbm.xml` files and linked them to the project. Is there an easy way to do it ?

Also, it often gives the error 500 internal server error.

Comment: it is difficult to give any suggestion without sharing the error message or the code you have tried.

Comment: I am mostly interested in what exactly maven dependencies should I use for all of above(Hibernate with MySQL,JSP, SpringBoot web) to work.

Comment: And this is error massage: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at com.example.demo.MainController.getAllStudents(MainController.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
 at com.example.demo.MainController.getStudents(MainController.java:39) ~[classes/:na]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how `pom.xml` looks like for JPA, MySQL and Spring Boot, Web

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

For DB configuration use `application.properties` file

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp

logging.level=DEBUG
# Database
db.driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/CustomerData
db.username: root
db.password: admin

# Hibernate
hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.show_sql: true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: create
entitymanager.packagesToScan: org

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
```

Here we have resolved view as `.jsp` files

This should get you started.

More details [here](https://java2blog.com/spring-boot-hibernate-example/)

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies you would probably need are

[image]

Comment: Do some of these dependencies include ability to work with JSP?